# Using GLSurfaceView instead of SurfaceView with the camera preview app sample

Tags: android, camera, glsurfaceview

I am trying to use a GLSurfaceView instead of a normal SurfaceView with a camera application. The app simply display the camera preview frame on a surfaceview object. It works, but since i want to add opengl es rendering on the camera preview frame, i started by extending a GLSurfaceView class instead of a SurfaceView. Just that. The application seems to work, but sometimes it mulfunction (the app don't exit anymore if i press the back button) and it exit always with an error (when i close it, appears an alert box that says something like: "the app was interrupted due to an unexpected error").

Any idea?

Comment: AFAIK GlSurfaceView is not compatible with camera preview (don't know for sure though). As of API level 11 SurfaceTexture was introduced which allows you to update preview into texture directly instead.